# View changes in custom Rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thor, rails-generators

I'd like to view the affected files and/or changes that will be made prior to running a method in my custom Rails generator. I've looked through the docs for days and am beginning to think its not possible.

```
module Mygem
  module Generators
    class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base

      source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

      def copy_theme_files_to_app
        directory( source_paths[0] + "/mytemplate", Dir.pwd)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

In the example above I'm trying to copy the contents of a template directory into the destination app.

```
├── lib
│   ├── generators
│   │   ├── mygem
│   │   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   │   ├── mytemplate
│   │   │   │   │   ├── app
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── assets
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├── stylesheets
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├── application.scss
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├── custom.scss
```

Here are the contents of the "mytemplate" directory inside of my gem to give a little context. What I'm hoping to see inside of the generators `copy_theme_files_to_app` method is either an array of new paths to be generated/destroyed or showing the potential conflict between my template's application.scss file and the one in the app.

Is this possible?

Comment: Any chance the `-p` flag (for `pretend`) works? (as in `rails generate mygenerator -p`)

Comment: the --pretend flag does work in the sense that it doesn't copy the directory from the source to the destination. What I'm trying to do though is basically get the list of affected files that --pretend will output, but intercept that inside my generator's method before any action is taken.